# Maintaining constant data in ECS

Tags: entity-component-system

Investigating the topic of Entity Component System, I've faced to an issue of maintaining constant data of components.

For instance, having a movement component I'd like an according system to know the maximum speed of every entity.

Classically, I'd imagine this as the list with descriptions of entities containing speeds (and other such constants) of every type entity, that objects refer to.
But ECS tempts me to use variable description sets, that leads to another ECS for descriptions. And this looks like overhead.
That's regarding initializing components set withing the entity as well.

Maybe I miss something and there're more concise ways to do this?

Comment: The `amazon-ecs` tag is for the Amazon Web Services Elastic Container Service. It is not related to "Entity Component System".